# SQL changing a value to upper or lower case

Tags: sql, case, uppercase, lowercase

How do you make a field in a sql select statement all upper or lower case?

Example:

select firstname from Person

How do I make firstname always return upper case and likewise always return lower case?

Comment: What happens when you move to a database (or other repository - XML?) that does not support case changing? Consider doing this in code or performing case-insensitive operations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ajmastrean. I would fully agree with your statement and I rarely do any casing in SQL, which is why I forget how to do this from time to time when I do have a need it.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
SELECT UPPER(firstname) FROM Person

SELECT LOWER(firstname) FROM Person
```

Comment: Is this part of the SQL standard?

Answer (score 16):

LCASE or UCASE respectively.

Example:

```
SELECT UCASE(MyColumn) AS Upper, LCASE(MyColumn) AS Lower
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: UCASE for lower and LCase for Upper?

Comment: @Joshua - LCASE & UCASE are inherent within the SQL language itself not related to any specific implementation of SQL within a RDBMS. And I fixed the UCASE/LCASE for Lower/Upper thing.

Comment: Thank you. I gave you a up vote because you are right about ISO SQL vs an implementation.

Comment: `LCASE/UCASE` seem not to be known in Oracle (11.2.0.4.0), while `LOWER/UPPER` work

Comment: LCASE does not exist in Postgres! Not sure if oracle and postgres are just out of spec, but this cannot be depended on for cross-database functionality. like Andre said, use LOWER/UPPER. They're supported on MySQL, MsSql and Postgres

Answer (score 5):

SQL SERVER 2005:

```
print upper('hello');
print lower('HELLO');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Cirieno! I actually had this answer but wanted it to be documented on stack overflow since I only use this rarely I always forget it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LOWER function` and `UPPER function`. Like

```
SELECT LOWER('THIS IS TEST STRING')
```

Result:

```
this is test string
```

And

```
SELECT UPPER('this is test string')
```

result:

```
THIS IS TEST STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT lower(FIRST NAME) ABC
FROM PERSON
```

NOTE: `ABC` is used if you want to change the name of the column