# Converting all upper case to lower case in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update every row in my table from upper case to lower case. I searched everywhere but could not found relevant answer. I dont want it to select using `SELECT`. I would like to alter permanently may be using `ALTER`. 
I am using SQL server 2008.
Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you've "searched everywhere". The first google hit yields [`LOWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx). What i have used as keywords? The title of _your_ question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL changing a value to upper or lower case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341338/sql-changing-a-value-to-upper-or-lower-case)

Comment: but that are were irrelevant as i want to change for my whole tablee.. there are several responses in google. And by the way google result changes with respect to the location may be you have got the correct result.. please share with me

Comment: You know what _change_ in sql means? You don't want to change the type of a column but to _update_ the values.

Comment: no i dont really know about change.. i am a newbie

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name SET col1 = LOWER(col1), col2 = LOWER(col2), col3 = LOWER(col3);
```

HTH

Edit: Updating multiple columns. Just keep on adding columns like above. There is no direct automated way to update all the columns with a single command. Well, technically it may be possible using `cursors`, but I would advise against it since this looks like a one time process and you are better off with writing a command once and for all.

Comment: but this will update a single column.. Please re read my question. As i have written that how to change the upper lower case for the whole table and not only for single column.. Your quick response is appreciated SIR.

Comment: As SQL statement dont have a `WHERE` clause, all table will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using string functions:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = LOWER(MyColumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`LOWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx) function. You'll need to `UPDATE` your table:

```
UPDATE mytable SET charfld1=LOWER(charfld1), charfld2=LOWER(charfld2), ...
```

Put all your textual fields after the `SET`.

Comment: please elaborate further

Comment: Just replace charfld1 with the name of your first text column, charfld2 with the name of your second, etc...