# Change all column names to lowercase Postgresql

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plpgsql

I am having an issue with my postgresql database. I added 5 Tables with a lot of data and a lot of columns. Now I noticed I added the columns with a mix of upper and lowercase letters, which makes it difficult to query them using sqlalchemy or pandas.read_sql_query, because I need double quotes to access them.
Is there a way to change all values in the column names to lowercase letters with a single command?

Im new to SQL, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) with a `FOR LOOP` over the table columns:

```
DO $$
DECLARE row record;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT table_schema,table_name,column_name
             FROM information_schema.columns
             WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND 
             table_name   = 'table1'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I RENAME COLUMN %I TO %I',
      row.table_schema,row.table_name,row.column_name,lower(row.column_name));  
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f5a157d74293e0e1ba46f31ec8799a9c)

Comment: @Elias glad it helped. one last thing: I did a small modification in my last edit -> it takes different schemas into account in the `alter table` statement. cheers and happy coding

Comment: Also, just so this is complete: I had to put "row record;"  one line under the "Declare" part and add an indent for it to work for me.

Comment: @Elias that's odd. Your client is getting confused with the indentation :-D which client are you using?

Comment: Im trying to do as much as I can from the python console (spyder), but I did this particular bit in pgAdmin 4. Any better recommendations? ;)

EDIT: I did get an update alert though, maybe I should do that haha

Comment: @Elias I only use `pgAdmin` and `psql`.. and so far they haven't complained about such things :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to simply ensure that the query returns lowercase (without changing the original entries), you can simply input:

```
select lower(variable) from table;
```

On the other hand, if you wish to actually change the case in the table itself, you must use an UPDATE command.

```
UPDATE table SET variable = LOWER(variable);
```

Comment: and the variable is my column name? Is is possible to do that for all my columns at once or do I have to run it seperately?

Comment: Yes, the variable is your column name. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a direct way to update all columns simultaneously. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088573/converting-all-upper-case-to-lower-case-in-sql-server/26088609

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
 SELECT LOWER(column) FROM my_table;
```

Comment: I think I need to update the table, like Michael said.

Is it normal though that I cannot select the columns without double quotes if they are written in upper case?